# Return the values of max count of rows with the same values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have `table_schedule(id,instructorNumber,time,date,cpNumber,user_id);`

Is it possible to output the values of instructorNumber,time, etc. with the same highest  occurence with same values?

sorry I am new in sql, so I am hoping that someone can help me to the query

Comment: Mysql is the dbms I am using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just group by all the fields you need for "same value comparison", order by count desc (so the result with most occurences will be first), and take first.

```
select 
instructorNumber, time, date, cpNumber
from table_schedule
group by instructorNumber, time, date, cpNumber
order by count(*) desc
LIMIT 1
```

you may use this as a join on a main query if you want more than one result.

Comment: I keep on getting resource id #, sorry I am beginner

Comment: I used this $query = "SELECT time  From table_schedule group by time order by count(*) desc LIMIT 1 ";

Comment: @tomjerry and you've got an error with this query ? Did you try it in phpmyadmin, before trying to put this in your code ? See this : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a42f1/1

Comment: oh, it is correct in phpmyadmin, after the query, I stored it in $result = mysql_query($query); then in Php page <?php echo $result ?>.Is the process correct?

Comment: @tomjerry : well, didn't do PHP for years, so I wouldn't be a big help for that part ;)

Answer (score 0):

First group by the values you want to compare by and count. Get the maximum count (in MySQL you can use LIMIT for that). Then do the same group-by query again and take only the results HAVING the maximum count. Use GROUP_CONCAT to get a list of IDs in a string.

```
select instructorNumber, time, date, cpNumber, user_id, group_concat(id) as ids
from table_schedule
group by instructorNumber, time, date, cpNumber, user_id
having count(*) =
(
  select count(*)
  from table_schedule
  group by instructorNumber, time, date, cpNumber, user_id
  order by count(*) desc limit 1
);
```